# Telerik MVC Grid does not display data

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using version 2011.2.914 of the controls. Whenever I try to bind data from my controller to a view, **I can't get the data inside the collection to display on the grid**. I get the "**No records to display**" message from the grid.

I want to point out that if I am **not** using the Telerik grid, the data comes out fine (see below):
 **Controller without Telerik Grid**

```
IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();
                     return View("Index", customerList);
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Index";
}
<h2>Customer Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Company
        </th>
        <th>
            FirstName
        </th>
        <th>
            LastName
        </th>
        <th>
            Address1
        </th>
        <th>
            Address2
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            State
        </th>
        <th>
            Zip
        </th>
        <th>
            HomePhone
        </th>
        <th>
            CellPhone
        </th>
        <th>
            Website
        </th>
        <th>
            IMAddress
        </th>
        <th>
            CreatedDate
        </th>
        <th>
            UpdatedDate
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @if (ViewData.Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zip)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomePhone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CellPhone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Website)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IMAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CustomerID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CustomerID })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

I have tried ServerSide and Ajax Binding. Both don't work. I have searched the Telerik site and the web and can't find out what is missing.

**What do I need to do in order to resolve this and get the data in my grid?**

Here is the code in my Customer controller for the Ajax binding (which is what I really want). Upon return of getting the data, I have an image file that I saved where the data is in the customerList collection (***there is no option to attach any files in StackOverflow***, so I can't show you).

When the View is being rendered, I captured data while debugging for several objects. 
When cycling through the grid during the binding, I captured data in another file.

**Controller using Telerik Grid:**
    using Telerik.Web.Mvc;
    public class CustomerController : Controller
         {

```
[GridAction]
         public ActionResult Index()
         {
                     IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();
                     return View(new GridModel<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>
                     {
                         Data = customerList
                     });

         }
 }
```

Below, is the code in my associated View. btw, all the bound columns have intellisense that pop up for the columns in my model. This is for the Index action within the Customer controller.

```
@model Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridModel<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Customer Index";
 }
 <h2>
     Customer Index</h2>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
 <table>
     @(Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>()
   .Name("Customers")
   .Columns(columns =>
 {
     columns.Bound(o => o.Email);
     columns.Bound(o => o.Company);
     columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName);
     columns.Bound(o => o.LastName);
     columns.Bound(o => o.Address1);
     columns.Bound(o => o.Address2);
     columns.Bound(o => o.City);
     columns.Bound(o => o.State);
     columns.Bound(o => o.Zip);
     columns.Bound(o => o.HomePhone);
     columns.Bound(o => o.CellPhone);
     columns.Bound(o => o.Website);
     columns.Bound(o => o.IMAddress);
     columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
     columns.Bound(o => o.UpdatedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
 }).DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Index", "Customer"))
 .Pageable()
 .Sortable()
 .Scrollable()
 .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
 .Filterable())
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a conflic with your Index action method since that you have a View that is referenced to it. The first test to do is to show your grid without playing with Ajax or anything else.

Try this to initialize your grid when your View Index is build. Notice the **Model.Data** that i'm using in the Grid constructor:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>(Model.Data)
   .Name("Customers")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(o => o.Email);
       columns.Bound(o => o.Company);
       ...
   }))
```

If it work, then you should try to create another Action method with another name. In my projects, i do this:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult GetYeagerTechGridData()
{
    IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();
    return View(new GridModel<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>
    {
        Data = customerList
    });
}
```

and use your grid that way:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>()
   .Name("Customers")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(o => o.Email);
       columns.Bound(o => o.Company);
       ...
   })
   .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetYeagerTechGridData", "Customer")))
```

Comment: Putting the (Model.Data) solved the issue!!! That's something Telerik doesn't even have in the docs to specify. Thank you so much. As a side note, when the data is displayed, it's all squished together and not aligned with the grid columns. Is there a property on the grid I can set to take care of this?

Comment: Also, are there any properties to change the background/forground of the default properties on the grid? I can hardly make out the data....

Comment: Probably that you have'nt imported the Telerik's stylesheet to your web page. After that, if you want to change the color, you will have to override the stylesheet with your own

Comment: That was something I should have thought of, but still didn't fix it. I added the following link in the page: <link href="../../Content/2011.2.712/telerik.windows7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: you also need to add telerik.common.min.css before telerik.windows7.min.css

Comment: Still doesn't work... I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml file. <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/2011.2.712/telerik.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/2011.2.712/telerik.windows7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: can you confirm that the Telerik's CSS files are really imported to your web page. You can do that with Firebug. And just to be sure, you've told that you are using the version 2011.2.914. Are you sure you are using the right directory because you are importing your files from the 2011.2.712 directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4050/discussion-between-alexandre-jobin-and-sagesky36)

Comment: My mistake... You were correct. It is v712 and I was referring to 914. However.... the data now populates across the entrie grid (which is what I want), but now the columns are squished together and not in alignment with the grid data. Is there a Telerik property I need to set for this or is it still a CSS issue?